# "Response too large to return" on simple SELECT in BigQuery, even with allowLargeResults=True?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery with Python. I am trying to work out how to run a simple `SELECT` query, but I am getting errors about large results.

I have tested my query in the BigQuery interface before writing it in Python. It runs fine, returns 1 row, takes 4.0 seconds and processes 18.2GB. The underlying table is about 150GB, 200m rows.

This is my code:

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
try:
    query_request = bigquery_service.jobs()
    query_data = {
        "allowLargeResults": True,
        'query': (
            'SELECT org_code, item_code FROM [mytable] ',
            "WHERE (time_period='201501') ",
            "AND item_code='0212000AAAAAAAA' ",
            "AND (org_code='B82005') "
            "LIMIT 10;"
        )
    }
    print ' '.join(query_data['query'])
    response = query_request.query(
        projectId=project_id,
        body=query_data).execute()
    job_ref = response['jobReference']
    print 'job_ref', job_ref

except HttpError as err:
    print('Error: {}'.format(err.content))
    raise err
```

This is the output I get:

```
SELECT org_code, item_code FROM [mytable]  WHERE (time_period='201501')  AND (item_code='0212000AAAAAAAA')  AND (org_code='B82005') LIMIT 10;
Error: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "responseTooLarge",
    "message": "Response too large to return. Consider setting allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Response too large to return. Consider setting allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors"
 }
}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "query.py", line 93, in <module>
    main(args.project_id)
  File "query.py", line 82, in main
    raise err
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/824821804911/queries?alt=json returned "Response too large to return. Consider setting allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors">
```

There are a couple of different things that confuse me about this:

1. It says I should use `allowLargeResults`, even though I already am.
2. It's giving me a warning about large results, although this is a straightforward `SELECT` query with no grouping, and it returns 1 row.

I understand that the warning will fire if any part of the query processing becomes too large. But I don't really know how to get round this, given the query I'm doing is just a `SELECT` with no grouping etc. I'm not even using `SELECT *`.

Surely the whole point of BigQuery is that it can handle this kind of thing?

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: UPDATE: I tried adding `destinationTable: foo` to `query_data` as suggested by @mikhail-berlyant below, but I'm still seeing the same `Response too large to return` error.

Comment: Looks like you're doing a `LIMIT 10`... if you're returning less than 10 rows it is very surprising that this will report responseTooLarge. Can you provide a job id of a job that hit this error? are org_code or item_code heavily repeated, perhaps?

Comment: Here's a job ID: `job_2GHOOY0uS186SA7IUm5zLOhJTvc`. I suspect it's most likely an error somewhere in my config.

Comment: See my answer below (TL;DR: you need to call a different API to use a destination table / allowLargeResults)

Answer (score 3):

If `configuration.query.allowLargeResults` is set to true - it also requires `configuration.query.destinationTable`

You should either add destinationTable object or (as your output seems to be small) set allowLargeResults to false

> Added example of configuration:

```
'query': {
    'query': 'my_query_text',
    'destinationTable': {
        'projectId': 'my_project',
        'datasetId': 'my_dataset',
        'tableId': 'my_table'
    },
    'createDisposition': 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    'writeDisposition': 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    'allowLargeResults': True
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding `destinationTable: foo` to `query_data`, but I'm still seeing the same `Response too large to return` error.

Comment: The output is small, yes, and the query is straightforward: so I don't understand why I'm getting the error about large results!

Comment: destination table is an object. You have to provide destinationTable.projectId, destinationTable.datasetId and destinationTable.tableId

Comment: as I suggested in my answer  - just remove allowLargeResult as it requires destination table or set properly destination table :o)

Comment: Thanks. Tried removing `allowLargeResults` but still get the same error code about the response being too large, whether or not I remove the `LIMIT` clause. I'll now try adding a destination table and see if that helps!

Comment: just in case - i added configuration example. Also  - if still doesnt work  - try to define your query text and assign it to variable outside of configuration and then use this variable

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at your job; you're not setting allowLargeResults, and you're also not using a limit or a filter (your query was essentially just selecting two fields from the table).

There are two ways to run a query in the BigQuery API. The first is to call the `jobs.query()`. This is the 'simple' way, but it is lacking some bells and whistles. The other is to call `jobs.insert()` with a query job configuration. This has full support for things like setting a destination table and allowing large results.

It looks like you are calling the former (`jobs.query()`), but you want `jobs.insert()`.

It is easier than it sounds to use the more fully-fledged `jobs.insert()` call. You can get the job id back from the `jobs.insert()` call, and then pass that to `jobs.getQueryResults()` to get the query results; the format of the results returned by that method is the same as calling `jobs.query()`. Check out the sample code [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/api/async_query.py).

Comment: Thanks for this, but are you sure I wasn't using a filter? The job ID I sent you admittedly wasn't using a `LIMIT`, but it was definitely using a `WHERE` clause - in the BigQuery UI returns 61 results.

Comment: To be clear, I still have the output from the job ID that I sent you, and the query string it printed before making the API call looked like this: `SELECT field1, field2 FROM [project:dataset.table]  WHERE field2='0212000AAAAAAAA' AND (field1='B82005')`.

Comment: RIGHT - supplying `query_data['query']` as a string rather than a tuple fixes the problem! I see what the problem was: I'd copied my code from the Python example here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart#query but while editing it, I'd mindlessly assumed that `query_data['query']` was a tuple, and put commas after each element. Could I respectfully suggest you change the example to use simpler Python syntax? The unfamiliar `('abc' 'def' 'ghi')` multiline notation for strings may trip other people up - I know it's PEP8, but it's not that well-known, to me at least.

Comment: Tanks for the link, but what is best practice. Is it:    `bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)` or 
    `bq = googleapiclient.discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2')`

Answer (score 0):

Let's clear some things which are wrong here.

Queries that return large results are subject to additional limitations:

- You must specify a destination table.
- You can't specify a top-level ORDER BY, TOP or LIMIT clause. Doing so negates the benefit of using allowLargeResults, because the query output can no longer be computed in parallel.
- Window functions can return large query results only if used in conjunction with a PARTITION BY clause.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query) is clear about `configuration.query.allowLargeResults` If true, allows the query to produce arbitrarily large result tables at a slight cost in performance. Requires destinationTable to be set.

Comment: Thanks for the information. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've tried removing the `LIMIT` clause, and I've also set `query_data['destinationTable'] = 'foo'`. However, I'm still getting the same error. I don't understand the part about "window functions" - I don't think I'm using one?

Comment: You don't use window functions. Test your code with simple query. Start by seeing if the query is written to the table you set.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already massively simplified the query down from the one i actually want to run! Is it even possible to simplify it further, given that it's just a simple select that returns one row?

Comment: I am trying to suggest to get first a simple query from public data set or a small table to run. I think the problem here is to get the library you are using to work well for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Is [mytable] possibly a view rather than a table?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue. I solved it by using job.insert() instead of job.query(). Specify true for **allowLargeResults**. Also give **destinationTable** for query.

Here is the sample code:

```
job_data = {
"jobReference": {
  "projectId": "project_id"
},
"configuration": {
  "query": {
     "query": "query",
     "allowLargeResults": "True",
     "destinationTable": {
        "projectId": "project_id",
        "tableId": "table_name",
        "datasetId": "dataset_name"
     }
  }
}
}

return bigquery.jobs().insert(
    projectId="project_id",
    body=job_data).execute()
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this and return a dataframe? Like with read_gbq http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_gbq.html